# Strange blue and orange edges on css animated font

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm seeing some odd behavior in on a full bar symbol animated using CSS3. In some browsers the symbol develops blue and orange edges along its sides. Have not been able to figure out why.

CSS:

```
/* blink cursor*/
span#textblink {
color: #fff;
font-family: "Lucida Console";
animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate;  
-moz-animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate; 
-webkit-animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate;
-o-animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="linkbg">
<a href="developers.html" id="dev-link">DreaMLer::Wanted.developers()</a>
<span id="textblink">█</span>
</div>
```

Example page: [Dreamler.se](http://dreamler.se/index.html) - The effect seems to develop over a short period of time.

Comment: and these "some browsers" would be...? Somehow I don't think Lynx or `telnet port 80` will be affected...

Comment: tested with safari 6.0.2 and ff 17.0.1 - there are no problems

Comment: No exhaustive testing done. Problem appears on Windows versions:
Chrome 22.0.1229.26
Safari 5.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Oh the irony.

This really looks like a browser bug to me. I was able to reproduce it sporadically in Chrome 23.0.1271.95 m. It really looks like it's a problem with character overflowing the expected area very slightly and the area outside not being properly repainted. The blue on the left of the square makes the most sense, when you highlight the text then clear the highlight (which is blue) a 1px blue line is left on the left-hand side. Also note that when you highlight the single rectangle character, the highlight misses about 1px on the left and right sides.

One thing I tried was to add a 1px black border around the text:

```
span#textblink {
    color: #FFF;
    animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate;  
    -moz-animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate; 
    -webkit-animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: colorPulse 0.2s infinite alternate;

    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This seemed to solve the issue, however like we've seen, the issue is sporadic, so it may have just eluded my testing.

Otherwise you are likely stuck with one of the three options:

- Finding another character (possibly using a different font) which is slightly smaller
- Using jQuery to animate the character
- If all else fails, using a gif.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis of the problem. It makes sense - I'm able to reproduce this in safari and Chrome only so possibly a webkit issue. Have reported it to Google and Apple, and will follow your suggestions on solutions.